# User input filter for new dataframe in particular column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm trying to make a data frame considering user input, help me with if user select more than one value (like Desc as 730,740 or Vin_age as 63,64) then also it can filter that out for new dataframe.

```
answer = None 
while answer not in ("yes", "no"): 
        answer = input("Do u want to add filter? yes or no: ") 
        if answer == "yes":
            Des = list(input('Please enter Desc? (730, 750, 740, 640) =').split(',')) 
            Cate = list(input('Please enter Category?GKL, MKL, UKL =').split(',')) 
            Age = (int(s) for s in (input('Please enter VIN_Age?(In Months From 62-72) =').split(',')))
            Final_Data = Final_Data[(Final_Data['Desc'] == Des) & (Final_Data['VIN_Age'] == Age) & (Final_Data['Category'] == Cate)]
            Final_Data['Percentile'] = Final_Data["Total_Revenue"].rank(pct=True)
        elif answer == "no": 
            Final_Data['Percentile'] = Final_Data.groupby(['VIN_Age'])["Total_Revenue"].rank(pct=True) 
        else: 
            print("Please enter yes or no.")
```

Final_Data:

| VIN | Desc | Category | Vin_Age | Total_Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 730 | MKL | 64 | 5000 |
| v2 | 750 | GKL | 61 | 3000 |
| v3 | 640 | GKL | 63 | 3900 |
| v4 | 730 | UKL | 64 | 4000 |
| v5 | 740 | MKL | 61 | 3500 |

Comment: You should provide an example of the input data (text or DataFrame constructor)

Comment: @mozway i have added the sample of dataframe as  suggested..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isin(list of filter value)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method to filter more than 1 values from the input

```
import pandas as pd

Final_Data = pd.DataFrame({
    'VIN': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5'],
    'Desc': ['730', '750', '640', '730', '740'],
    'Category': ['MKL', 'GKL', 'GKL', 'UKL', 'MKL'],
    'VIN_Age': [64, 61, 63, 64, 61],
    'Total_Revenue': [5000, 3000, 3900, 4000, 3500]
    })


answer = None

while answer not in ("yes", "no"):
        answer = input("Do u want to add filter? yes or no: ")
        if answer == "yes":
            Des = list(input('Please enter Desc? (730, 750, 740, 640) =').split(','))
            Cate = list(input('Please enter Category?GKL, MKL, UKL =').split(','))
            Age = (int(s) for s in (input('Please enter VIN_Age?(In Months From 62-72) =').split(',')))
            Final_Data = Final_Data[(Final_Data['Desc'].isin(Des)) & (Final_Data['VIN_Age'].isin(Age)) & (Final_Data['Category'].isin(Cate))]
            Final_Data['Percentile'] = Final_Data["Total_Revenue"].rank(pct=True)
        elif answer == "no":
            Final_Data['Percentile'] = Final_Data.groupby(['VIN_Age'])["Total_Revenue"].rank(pct=True)
        else:
            print("Please enter yes or no.")

print(Final_Data)
```